# Confusing Lagrange multipliers question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Let $a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n$ be reals, we define a function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\ln(x_i)$, in addition, we are also given that $0 \cdot \ln(0)$ is defined to be $0$.

Find the supremum of $f$ on the domain $\Omega = \{x \in \mathbb R^n: x_i \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = 1\}$.

**What I did:**

$\Omega$ is closed and bounded and hence compact, and $f$ is continuous. It follows that $f$ admits a minimum and maximum (which confuses me as to why they asked for supremum and not maximum).

Let's look for the maximum when $x_i > 0$, by solving the system $\begin{cases}a_i-\ln(x_i)-1 = \lambda \\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = 1 \end{cases}$.

From the first $n$ equations we get $\ln(x_i) = a_i-1-\lambda$ or in other words $x_i = e^{a_i -1 -\lambda} > 0$

Plugging this to the constraint to find $\lambda$, we get $\lambda = \ln(\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{a_i}) - 1$, so $x_i = e^{a_i-\ln(\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{a_i})}$ is a potential maximum, or minimum, remember $f$ also attains a minimum.

Now we need to check what happens when $x_i$ is zero. This gives us an identical problem, but one dimension smaller. After that we need to check when $(x_i,x_j)$ are zero over all pairs. Then over all triples and so forth.

Surely this isn't the intended way. What's going on here?

Comment: The partial derivative with respect to $x_i$ when $x_i=0$ is $+\infty$ so for finding the maximum you don't need this dimension reduction thing.

Comment: @Ian I don't follow. If $x_n = 0$ then $f$ becomes $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_ix_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i\ln(x_i)$, where $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i = 1$. Basically the same problem but one dimension lower.

Comment: There is no partial derivative with respect to $x_1$ when $x_1$ is a known constant...Since it's a constant

Comment: You always differentiate at one point or another...but it is true that the partial derivative alone means little with the equality constraint there. Still, when $x_i=0$, there is some $x_j>1/n$, and you can increase $x_i$ by a small amount and decrease $x_j$ by that amount and increase the objective function in the process. So the maximizer has all positive components. (By contrast the minimizer is likely to be on the boundary.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite correct way.

Obtained solution for the stationary point
$$\hat x_i = \dfrac{e^{a_i}}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ne^{a_j}}$$
corresponds to the constraints.

The value is
$$f\left(\hat x\right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{a_ie^{a_i}}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ne^{a_j}} - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\dfrac{e^{a_i}}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ne^{a_j}}\log\dfrac{e^{a_i}}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ne^{a_j}}
 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{e^{a_i}}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ne^{a_j}}
\left(a_i - \log\dfrac{e^{a_i}}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ne^{a_j}}\right)\\
 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{e^{a_i}}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ne^{a_j}}
\left(\log e^{a_i} - \log e^{a_i}+\log{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ne^{a_j}}\right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\dfrac{e^{a_i}\log{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ne^{a_j}}}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ne^{a_j}} = \log{\sum\limits_{j=1}^ne^{a_j}}.$$
The task in every border is similar, with some subset of $\{a_i\}$ instead the issue set $\{a_i\}.$ So the stationary points values in the borders contain some part of the issue sum terms. At this time, last level sums, every of which contains the single value $a_i,$ present $1D$ tasks with zeros on the edges and correspond with the maxima.

Since $\forall(i)e^{a_i}>0,$ the value $f\left(\hat x\right)$ is maximum.

Comment: I am afraid $f$ does not increase to infinity on the border. Moreover, since $f$ is concave non constant, it has to reach a global minimum on a vertex of your convex domain, and any interior critical point (ie the gradient of $f$ is orthogonal to the hyperplane $x_1+ \ldots + x_n=0$) is a global maximum.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you! Fixed.

Comment: @Mindlack yes I know that, but what about when $x_i = 0$? We also need to check the border of the domain, and that's difficult in this case since we get an identical problem. You did not address that at all.

Comment: Oria Gruber: I did. I stated that if some interior point has a gradient with identical coordinates (ie the gradient of the restriction of the function to the affine hull of the simplex vanishes), then it is local, thus a global maximum, because the function is concave. It turns out that the $\hat{x}$ is such a point.

Comment: @Mindlack My reasons are written in the updated answer.

Comment: @OriaGruber My reasons are written in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a convex optimization problem (maximizing a convex function over a convex domain). The KKT conditions are therefore necessary and sufficient for global optimality.

The KKT conditions are: (1) stationarity, (2) primal feasibility, and (3) complementary slackness. The Lagrangian (including nonnegativity) is:
$$L(x,\lambda,\mu) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i - x_i \ln(x_i) + \mu_i x_i + \lambda x_i \right) - \lambda$$
The KKT conditions are:

1. $a_i - \ln(x_i)-1+\mu_i+\lambda=0$
2. $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$ and $x \geq 0$
3. $\mu_i x_i = 0$

The solution you found satisfies all conditions with $\mu_i=0$ and is therefore optimal.